# Simple HTML5/CSS3 background image transition on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, markup, transition

I'm trying to understand the *simplest* background transition possible using *only* **`HTML5`** and **`CSS3`**. Searching through stackoverflow I've learned it can be easily implemented using external libraries such as `jQuery` but for this project I've decided not relying on any of those.

**Markup**

```
<nav> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a id="foobar" href="http://www.google.com/search?q=foobar">Foobar</a></li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

**Styles**

```
body {
  background: url('background-default.png'), no-repeat;
}
#foobar a:hover {
   background: url('background-hover.png'), no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: // TODO;
  -moz-transition: // TODO;
  -o-transition: // TODO;
  -ms-transition: // TODO;
  transition: // TODO;
}
```

Comment: Use a CSS Sprite instead and change the background position value on hover for the transition effect.

Comment: @SalmanPK: Thanks much for the comment! I've considered _CSS Sprites_ but that wouldn't be doing any __transition__ (fade in/out) between the images, would it? In any case would you mind providing a little code sample about your suggested approach?

Comment: The only transitions you can do on background images are to change the position and other numeric properties, you can't make them fade into each other.

Comment: @robertc: Thanks for the contribution. Would you mind posting this comment as an answer so I'd eventually accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can't transition the `background-image` property but you can get the sort of effect you're looking for if you're willing to add extra markup and then transition the opacity.  So you'll have some markup like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="no-icon.png">
      <img src="yes-icon.png">
      <a id="foobar" href="http://www.google.com/search?q=foobar">Foobar</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then set the transition on the images, absolute position them (so they'll be like backgrounds), and hide one of them by default (I've left out the vendor extensions for clarity):

```
nav li img {
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: 1.5s;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav li img:first-child {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Then swap the opacity values on `li:hover`:

```
nav li:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}
nav li:hover img:first-child {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Here's a full working example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/AQbyC/).  Not an ideal solution because you have to add extra markup, but it'll work.

Comment: Great example, used this with a couple other CSS tweaks...replaced some JavaScript that was doing this, the performance gain was absolutely ridiculous!!! Frames went from 60.00ms to roughly 16/17.00ms, no JS overhead =)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of the code I use to achieve this. The images are sprites which each contain normal and hover state. The trick is to add the img to both li and a, and to use opacity to change the appearance of the image. You can then use css3 transitions to make this appear smoother.

```
<ul id="homenav">
    <li class="h"><a href="#><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class="i"><a href="#"><span>Inloggen</span></a></li>
    <li class="v"><a href="#"><span>Voorbeelden</span></a></li>
</ul>

#homenav li.h, #homenav li.h a        {background-image: url('img/btn_home.gif');}
#homenav li.i, #homenav li.i a        {background-image: url('img/btn_inloggen.gif');}
#homenav li.v, #homenav li.v a        {background-image: url('img/btn_voorbeelden.jpg');}

#homenav li     {background-position: 0 170px;}
#homenav li a   {background-position: 0 0;}
#homenav li a:hover
        {opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .8s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity .8s ease-in;
        -o-transition: opacity .8s ease-in;
        transition: opacity .8s ease-in;}

#homenav a      {display: block; height: 100%;}
#homenav a span {display: none;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mirthe - do you mind refactoring your code to make it compatible with the code snippets provided in the question?